# SQL Server scripting permissions for my database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am deploying a web application, this is not a production application but it's important to me none the less. I am deploying it via dacpac and I would like to script out the creation of a login / user account with sql server authentication.

At minimum this users will need access to read, write, update, and delete on all of the database tables, these tables are separated into different schema's. The user will also need access to execute all stored procedures and functions in my database.

How would i script this out? What permissions do I give to the user?

This is what i got so far, I actually have no database tables in the dbo schema, but since this was the default for sql server i figured it might make sense to leave it the default for the user, but i would like to finish this script giving explicit access to all tables in a given schema with all of the permissions i listed, as well as permission to sprocs and functions.

```
CREATE LOGIN [webProcessLogin] WITH PASSWORD = 'Pa$$word';
CREATE USER webProcessUser FOR LOGIN 
    [webProcessLogin] 
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];
GRANT CONNECT TO [webProcessUser]
```

Comment: The respective permissions would be `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`.

Comment: yeah, so far i got that but i am unable to connect to the database with the user, I ran "GRANT CONNECT TO [webProcessRole]" which my user is part of that role, but still not able to connect.